# Convert from different colors to different fonts?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, conversion, colors

I have been sent a docx-document (that I can convert intro HTML if you want) in 3 different colors: black, blue and green. The colors are different because the stand for different things. But I want to print it in a normal printer. So can I **convert from different colors to different fonts?** So that black=arial, blue=times, green=palatino or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Go into Word's Replace dialog (in Mac Word, you need the Advanced Find/Replace) and click the More button.

Click in the Find What box. Click the Format dropdown, Font, and select the colour you want to find (e.g. black).

Click in the Replace With box. Click the Format dropdown, Font, and select the font and size that you want.

Replace All, then repeat with suitable values for the other two colours.